# Views exposed form as a block pure Ajax

Tags: 7, views

Building a view that has a few filters and i would like to have a sidebar block with them inside, just like an "eshop" with the sidebar filters.

The default behaviour is a get request. How i can make the exposed form block work with ajax?

Comment: Have you enabled the ajax settings in views?

Comment: Yes and i am using the latest views version.

Comment: If the exposed filter's block of same view is placed on same page the ajax should work.

Comment: If i exposed the form as block i don't get an ajax like behaviour. If i don't use the block everything work as it should.

Comment: I used exposed form as block on the same page and it worked for me.